# How to run a subprocess with Python, wait for it to exit and get the full stdout as a string?

Tags: python, subprocess

So I noticed `subprocess.call` while it waits for the command to finish before proceeding with the python script, I have no way of getting the stdout, except with `subprocess.Popen`. Are there any alternative function calls that would wait until it finishes? (I also tried `Popen.wait`)

NOTE: I'm trying to avoid `os.system` call

```
result = subprocess.Popen([commands...,
                        self.tmpfile.path()], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = result.communicate()
print out+"HIHIHI"
```

my output:

```
HIHIHI
```

NOTE: I am trying to run `wine` with this.

Comment: *subprocess.call()* can be used to read out/err. [please check the manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). ensure the command doesn't generate lot of output.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I am using the following construct, although you might want to avoid `shell=True`.  This gives you the output and error message for any command, and the error code as well:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# wait for the process to terminate
out, err = process.communicate()
errcode = process.returncode
```

Comment: I tried this and I still get empty results :s not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the content of `cmd`?

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat maybe you need to check the out var, or the err one.

Answer (score 24):

```
subprocess.check_output(...)
```

calls the process, raises if its error code is nonzero, and otherwise returns its stdout. It's just a quick shorthand so you don't have to worry about `PIPE`s and things.

Comment: This has issues with `wine` I believe. Sorry, I'll add that to my question.

Comment: This is a great feature, only in Python 2.7 or newer though.

Answer (score 19):

If your process gives a huge stdout and no stderr, `communicate()` might be the wrong way to go due to memory restrictions.

Instead,

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# wait for the process to terminate
for line in process.stdout: do_something(line)
errcode = process.returncode
```

might be the way to go.

`process.stdout` is a file-like object which you can treat as any other such object, mainly:

- you can `read()` from it
- you can `readline()` from it and
- you can iterate over it.

The latter is what I do above in order to get its contents line by line.

Comment: Could you explain to me what the for loop does?

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat It reads the `stdout` produced from the process line by line and processes each line.

Comment: I get  `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`   for the operation `for line in process.stdout`

Comment: @glglgl You might want to change process(line) to something like do_something(line) to avoid confusion with the process identifier/variable that you set on the first line. :)

Comment: do_something(line) was not clear for me. I just ask for the display of each output.
    
    for line in process.stdout: print ("stdout :", line)
    for line in process.stderr: print ("stderr :", line)

Answer (score 3):

With Python 3.8 this workes for me. For instance to execute a python script within the venv:

```
import subprocess
import sys
res = subprocess.run(
        [
          sys.executable, # venv3.8/bin/python
          'main.py', 
          '--help',
        ], 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
        text=True
)
print(res.stdout)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function

import shlex
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def shlep(cmd):
    '''shlex split and popen
    '''
    parsed_cmd = shlex.split(cmd)
    ## if parsed_cmd[0] not in approved_commands:
    ##    raise ValueError, "Bad User!  No output for you!"
    proc = Popen(parsed_command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    return (proc.returncode, out, err)
```

... In other words let shlex.split() do most of the work.  I would NOT attempt to parse the shell's command line, find pipe operators and set up your own pipeline.  If you're going to do that then you'll basically have to write a complete shell syntax parser and you'll end up doing an awful lot of plumbing.

Of course this raises the question, why not just use *Popen* with the **shell=True** (keyword) option?  This will let you pass a string (no splitting nor parsing) to the shell and still gather up the results to handle as you wish.  My example here won't process any pipelines, backticks, file descriptor redirection, etc that might be in the command, they'll all appear as literal arguments to the command.  Thus it is still safer then running with **shell=True** ... I've given a silly example of checking the command against some sort of "approved command" dictionary or set --- through it would make more sense to normalize that into an absolute path unless you intend to require that the arguments be normalized prior to passing the command string to this function.

Comment: I like this example, raising attention to shlex as a proper way to parse command line input. Humor in the example, too (shlep() and the exception comments). :)