# Python subprocess Popen get command output when using os.waitpid()

Tags: python, subprocess

How to extract the stdout of the executed command when I use waitpid() during subprocess.Popen()?

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
retcode = os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)[1]
```

When I use,

```
p.communicate()
```

it returns empty ('','')

ok, I use it like this now:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
err = p.stderr.read()
retcode = os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)[1]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a subprocess with Python, wait for it to exit and get the full stdout as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398261/how-to-run-a-subprocess-with-python-wait-for-it-to-exit-and-get-the-full-stdout)

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188